# How to calculate the intersection point between a straight and a triangle (in python)?

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, python

**Introduction:**

I try to program a small ray tracer application in which I have planed to reflect a  ray on the surface of a triangle like the following sketches shows:

[image: ray/triangle intersection]

**Conditions:**

Given are the vectors from the triangle vertexes **A**,**B**,**C** and as well the two vectors **P** and **Q** from the ray.

For solving this problem I need firstly the intersection point between the triangle and the ray (if this exists)
I have found a interesting source, which describes these scenario really good.

[CS465 Notes: Simple ray-triangle intersection http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs465/2003fa/homeworks/raytri.pdf](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs465/2003fa/homeworks/raytri.pdf)

In this paper is the following formula to see:

[image: Simple ray-triangle intersection]

**Problem:**

I tried to implement these formula in the following python code:

legend (python/formula):

*triangle_n = n*

rP = o

rD = d

p = tA -->?

```
def triangle_ray_intersection(tA, tB, tC, rP, rD):
triangle_xyAC = tC - tA
triangle_xyAB = tB - tA
triangle_xyBC = tC - tB

triangle_n = np.cross(triangle_xyAB, triangle_xyAC)
delta_t = np.dot((rP - tA), triangle_n)/np.dot(triangle_n,rD)
intersection_i = rD + delta_t * rP


cross_a = np.dot(np.cross(triangle_xyAB,(intersection_i-tA)),triangle_n)
cross_b = np.dot(np.cross(triangle_xyBC,(intersection_i-tB)),triangle_n)
cross_c = np.dot(np.cross(triangle_xyAC,(intersection_i-tC)),triangle_n)
```

But I get everytime some wrong results. I believe that I don't understand what the author from the paper means with the variable **p**. I thought  he means that **p** is just a point on the plane (and I can take a point like the given **A**, **B** or **C** from the triangle) but I think thats not correct. Because I get some wrong intersection point.

*p.s cross_(a,b,c) are the values which should be => 0 also the condition that the intersection point is in the triangle.*

**Question:**

Which value/variable do I have to take for the given variable **p** from the formula?

How i have to implement it, that I get the correct intersection point between the straight(ray) and the triangle?

How I get this value/variable from my given arguments?

Thank's you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a triangle by three vertex $\Delta\to(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ and $ p = (x,y,z)$ we have

$$
(p_1-p_2)\times(p_3-p_2) = \vec n\\
p_0 =\frac 13(p_1+p_2+p_3)
$$

are respectively the normal vector to the plane containing $\Delta$ and a point pertaining to $\Delta$.

so we have  $\Pi\to (p-p_0)\cdot \vec n = 0$ as the plane containing $\Delta$

Now, given a line

$$
L\to p = q_0 + \lambda\vec w
$$

we have that $\Pi \cap L = p_i$ is obtained by solving

$$
(q_0-p_0+\lambda \vec w)\cdot\vec n = 0
$$

giving

$$
p_i = q_0-\left(\frac{(q_0-p_0)\cdot\vec n}{\vec w\cdot\vec n}\right)\vec w
$$

now $p_i\in \Delta\Rightarrow (p_1-p_2)\lambda_1 +(p_3-p_2)\lambda_2 = p_i-p_2$ such that $(\lambda_1\ge 0)\cap(\lambda_2\ge 0)$ and $(p_1-p_3)\lambda_1 +(p_2-p_3)\lambda_2 = p_i-p_3$ such that $(\lambda_1\ge 0)\cap(\lambda_2\ge 0)$

`import numpy as np`


`def dif(u,v):
    s = []
    for i in range(len(u)):
        s.append(u[i]-v[i])
    return s`


`def add(u,v):
    s = []
    for i in range(len(u)):
        s.append(u[i]+v[i])
    return s`


`def prod(u,c):
    v = []
    for i in range(len(u)):
        v.append(u[i]*c)
    return v`


`def isin(p,p1,p2,p3):
    u = dif(p1,p2)
    v = dif(p3,p2)
    w = dif(p,p2)
    l1 = np.dot(u,w)
    if l1 < 0: 
        return False
    l2 = np.dot(v,w)
    if l2 < 0: 
        return False
    u = dif(p1,p3)
    v = dif(p2,p3)
    w = dif(p,p3)
    l1 = np.dot(u,w)
    if l1 < 0: 
        return False
    l2 = np.dot(v,w)
    if l2 < 0: 
        return False
    return True`

 
`p1 = [10,0,0]
p2 = [0,10,0]
p3 = [0,0,10]
q0 = [10,13,15]
w  = [1,1,1]`


`u  = dif(p1,p2)
v  = dif(p3,p2)
n  = list(np.cross(u,v))
p0 = prod(add(add(p1,p2),p3),1/3.)
pi = add(q0,prod(w,-np.dot(dif(q0,p0),n)/np.dot(w,n)))`


`if isin(pi,p1,p2,p3):
    print(pi, " internal point")
else:
    print(pi, " external point")`

Comment: Thank's you for your invested time. I implemented your idea and it works fine. What do you mean with the variable w? Is that the second position vector from the ray?

Comment: @helmi $w$ was introduced to avoid naming conflict with the script variables. I edited the answer accordingly . Now $\vec w$ is the line direction vector.

Answer (score 0):

The points inside the triangle can be described as the (convex) vector sum

$$\textbf A+b\,\textbf{AB}+c\,\textbf{AC}$$

where $b\ge0,c\ge0,b+c\le1$.

The points on the (half) ray are

$$\textbf P+q\,\textbf{PQ}.$$

under the condition $q\ge0$.

So to find the intersection, you can solve the vector equation

$$\textbf A+b\,\textbf{AB}+c\,\textbf{AC}=\textbf P+q\,\textbf{PQ}$$
or
$$b\,\textbf{AB}+c\,\textbf{AC}+q\,\textbf{QP}=\textbf{AP},$$

which is equivalent to a $3\times3$ linear system. Then check that the inequalities are satisfied.

Comment: Thank's you for your time and correcting my question